# django-admin "ModuleNotFoundError:" after change in settings structure for development & production

Tags: django, django-admin, django-settings

**Background**

I have recently started to learn Python Django. I read that it was good practice to have separate settings file for different environments. Consequently I have tried to implement something similar to what is describe in the "Simple Package Organization for Environments" section of this wiki: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings

**Problem**

When I now run a django-admin command I get a ModuleNotFoundError. Below I have copy pasted the error log I get for "django-admin check --deploy". "python manage.py runserver --settings=CollegeComp.settings.development" works fine.

**Things I've tried**

I was reading that I may have to reset the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable in my virtual environment. I entered "set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=CollegeComp.settings.development" but I still get the same error.

**Python path**

When I type the following in the shell with my virtual environment activated:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

I get the following:

```
['C:\\Users\\myusername\\Documents\\UdemyDjango\\MyPersonalProject\\College-Project-master\\CollegeComp', 
'C:\\Users\\myusername\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\python37.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\myusername\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\myusername\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\myusername\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv',
'C:\\Users\\myusername\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**Error log**

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\Scripts\django-admin-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 329, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 220, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 214, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CollegeComp'
```

**My project directory**

```
CollegeComp
|-CollegeComp
  |-settings
    |-__init__.py
    |-base.py     
    |-development.py 
    |-local.py 
    |-production.py
  |-__init__.py 
  |-urls.py  
  |-wsgi.py
|-<my apps>
```

**base.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR =  os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
<rest of standard Django settings.py code>
```

**development.py**

```
from CollegeComp.settings.base import *

#Override base.py settings here
DEBUG = True


#Import local setting file
try:
    from CollegeComp.settings.local import *
except:
    pass
```

**local.py**

```
from CollegeComp.settings.base import *

#Override base settings here

DEBUG = True
```

**production.py**

```
from CollegeComp.settings.base import *

#Override base settings here

DEBUG = False


#Import local setting file
try:
    from CollegeComp.settings.local import *
except:
    pass
```

**System info**

Django version 2.1
Operating system: Windows 10
Python version: 3.7.0

I am grateful for any help I can get.